# Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms using Karma-Jasmine

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Using Karma runner with jasmine. After all the configuration done, I type on terminal the below command:

```
karma start public/javascripts/karma.conf.js
```

But I am getting the below error where my browser is getting closed.

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Connected on socket hDO3pMdVNGcBMDx4FI0w with id 60695552
WARN [Chrome 34.0.1847 (Mac OS X 10.9.2)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
```

I changed the browserNoActivityTimeout in Karma config to 50 seconds but still the same error. Its happening for both safari and chrome. I have not tried for other browsers.

I could not find much input fro other github threads on the same issue. Like changing port does not help either.

```
Karma Version: 0.12.16
Nodejs version: 0.10.22
Mac OS: 10.9.2
```

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Can you post your karma.conf.js?

For some reason Karma starts running the tests but there is no message from the browser...

Comment: I found the issue and resolve it. This was because requirejs was not included in the karma config where as all my controllers are getting loaded by requirejs. After including it in the frameworks, the issue was gone. I faced few more issues after that but was able to resolve and run a sample test case. One of the issues i faced is detailed in this link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689671/karma-jasmine-with-angular-requirejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the issue and resolve it. This was because requirejs was not included in the karma config where as all my controllers are getting loaded by requirejs. After including it in the frameworks, the issue was gone. I faced few more issues after that but was able to resolve and run a sample test case. i had to add "requirejs" in frameworks section in the karma conf file:: frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs']

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason. I'm getting the same error. I have this thread with my configs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127639/karma-jasmine-configuration-in-aurelia-1-disconnected-after-timeout

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by update my node from 10.4 to 12.2. It appears the socket.io that karma pull via npm was not compiling. I had run karma on two other machines just fine but the two with the 10.4 version of node had the warning below:

karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1103): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj
warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]

I did not bother tracking down whether it was the node version that was the problem or the npm version since npm gets upgraded by default when one upgrades node. Either way, upgrading node fixed the issue for me. If you have a hard dependency to 10.4 or whatever version of node you are one, try updating just your npm to a compartible version.