# Karma Typescript helloworld example fails

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I started working on a typescript project where I use Jasmine and Karma. Unfortunately Karma cannot execute the compiled unit tests, with this error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

Example project - I believe this is the most simple configuration to demonstrate the issue:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p ts",
    "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~2.4.1"
    ,"jasmine-core": "2.6.4"
    ,"jasmine": "2.6.0"
    ,"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53"
    ,"karma": "1.7.0"
    ,"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0"
    ,"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: ['js/*.spec.js'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

ts/tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
    ,"module": "amd"
    ,"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
    ,"outDir": "../js"
  }
}
```

ts/helloworld.ts

```
function returnHello() : string {
  return "Hello";
}

export default returnHello;
```

ts/helloworld.spec.ts

```
import returnHello from "helloworld";

describe("Some Test", function() {
  it("passes", () => expect(returnHello()).toEqual("Hello"));
});
```

Comment: Interesting, never thought of even trying to run jasmine/karma outside of an angular project.  Is this backend or frontend code you are testing?

Comment: Its frontend code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [karma jasmine with angular & requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689671/karma-jasmine-with-angular-requirejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was based on this question: [karma jasmine with angular & requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689671/karma-jasmine-with-angular-requirejs)

I uploaded a working example to github:
https://github.com/nagyzsolthun/typescript-amd-karma