# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module Hybrid Angular Webpack Karma

Tags: angular, requirejs, karma-runner

I'm trying to add unit tests to my project. For context, this is a hybrid angular1/angular4 app. The angular 4 portion of this was built with angular-cli. I'm only interested in running karma/jasmine on my angular 4 code, which resides in the path `src/app-ng/app`. All of the spec files are typescript `*.spec.ts` files which get transpiled to javascript when karma starts.

I've hit a dead end with my latest error `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define()`. From reading the [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch), there are 4 identified causes for this error:

> 1. Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API. Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that
>      have define() calls in them.
> 2. If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes named modules, and that an anonymous module that will have the same
>      name as one of the modules in that file is not loaded.
> 3. If the problem is the use of loader plugins or anonymous modules but the RequireJS optimizer is not used for file bundling, use the
>      RequireJS optimizer.
> 4. If the problem is the var define lint approach, use /*global define */ (no space before "global") comment style instead.*

None of these reasons seem to apply to me, but I might just be missing it. I do have this script tag in my index.html, but I tried removing it and it didn't help.
`<script src="//use.typekit.net/atv1krw.js"></script>
    <script>try { Typekit.load({async: true}); } catch (e) { }</script>`

I would really appreciate any insight you guys may have, and am happy to share more code if it is helpful.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'src/app-ng/app/home/home.component.spec.ts',
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: true },
      'test-main.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.ts': ['typescript']
    },
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        target: 'ES5',
        module: 'amd',
        noImplicitAny: false,
        noResolve: true,
        removeComments: true,
        concatenateOutput: false
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-requirejs'
    ],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    }
  })
}
```

home.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomeComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

result from `karma start ./karma.conf.js`
[image: result]

**EDIT**: I added test-main.js as per the answer's suggestion:

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
  if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    if (/spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
      tests.push(file);
    }
  }
}

requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '/base/src',

    paths: {
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore',
    },

    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    },

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests,

    // start test run, once Require.js is done
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Error is now: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [karma jasmine with angular & requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689671/karma-jasmine-with-angular-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

Tell Karma to not include your test file:

```
files: [
      { pattern: 'src/app-ng/app/home/home.component.spec.ts', included: false },
      'test-main.js'
  ],
```

You've set it to be compiled to an AMD module through TypeScript. By default files that are included in `files` are loaded through a `script` element. As you've discovered, you cannot load AMD modules with a `script` element. Using `included: false` tells Karma to serve the file but to avoid generating a `script` element. Instead, you load the module through RequireJS. As the Karma documentation [explains](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/plus/requirejs.html), it is the job of `test-main.js` to initiate loading the modules that contain your tests. So it must be listed  among your `files` and must be loaded with a `script` element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is helpful. I edited my question after implementing your suggestion. Your answer seemed to move things along, but now I'm getting 404 errors on some of the files that this test needs. See my edited question.