# Testing components with Font Awesome Icons Module

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm currently working in an Angular 6 project where I have imported several of the new font-awesome 5 icons using the Fort-awesome module for angular.

As expected, by doing so now some of my Unit Tests (Karma + Jasmine) won't pass due to not being able to render the fa-icon selectors in my pages.

I understand that I could use a CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in the TestBed for each component but I don't know if by doing so I may have other side effects that would make my unit tests less reliable (i.e. other sub-components may stop being tested).

Another option is to simply import the module in each of the required unit tests, and in each of those, also add the library.add() with the required icons. I do think, however, this could end up being tedious as there may be between 20 and 50 icons depending on the type of application.

I've also thought, but haven't tried yet, to add a stub module for the icons, so I simply "ignore" them. I think this could be reasonable, but not sure what the best practice would be in this case.

Below an excerpt of my imports in App.Module

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faLock, faHourglassHalf, faLockOpen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

And in the constructor

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(
      faHourglassHalf, // Task in progress
      faLockOpen, // Archive task
      faLock
    );
  }
}
```

Full repo here: https://github.com/Narshe1412/Code-Institute-Interactive-Frontend-Project/tree/taskman

As I know this is not debate forum I would simply ask:

- What are the side effects of using CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in this use case and, if reliability is an issue when using this, which of the other two options would be preferable?

Comment: Given that you're using the library, and that using an icon not added to (or accidentally removed from) the library could make your component fail, I would definitely not use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA. I would simply import a module importing the FontAwesomeModule and adding the icons to the library, both in the test, and in the AppModule.

Comment: Also make sure to check [library documentation](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/testing.md).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not like the other solutions, even if they may work. To me it seems unclean importing the `AppModule` in a unit test.

My solution is to separate the icons from the other stuff, as described below. This solution is kind of like the already accepted answer, but cleaner in my opinion:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faDownload, faUpload, faFileExport, faCircle, faChevronRight, faChevronDown, faPlus, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ FontAwesomeModule ],
  exports: [ FontAwesomeModule ]
})
export class IconsModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    // add icons to the library for convenient access in other components
    library.addIcons(faDownload, faUpload, faFileExport, faCircle, faChevronRight, faChevronDown, faPlus, faTimes);
  }
}
```

Then import the IconsModule wherever you need it, be it in the application itself or in a test:

AppModule:

```js
import { IconsModule } from './icons.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    IconsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Unit Test:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      imports: [
        ...
        IconsModule,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  ...

});
```

HTML:

```html
<fa-icon icon="download"></fa-icon>
```

Nice side effect: If you ever were to change the font library from Font Awesome to something else, this is much easier now, as you only have to change the `IconsModule` and the respective HTML code for the icons.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest, most modular approach, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can now use font-awesome testing module like this:

```
import {FontAwesomeTestingModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/testing';
```

---

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [ FontAwesomeTestingModule ]}).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to throw out a 'third' option. This is the approach that my team and I have been using and prefer.

The module brings in the FontAwesomeModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  exports: [
    FontAwesomeModule
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

The component that actually uses the font awesome icons imports only the icons it needs to know about.

```
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

import { faLock } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-example',
  template: '<fa-icon [icon]="faLock"></fa-icon>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  faLock = faLock;
}
```

Then in our `*.spec.ts` files, we have a setup like the following:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

Since the `FontAwesomeModule` is exported in the `AppModule` it will be available to the test bed here through the `AppModule` import. Since the icons are being imported explicitly in the component, there is no need to `library.add(...)` here either specifying all of the font awesome icons used in the module/component.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this approach and see if it works with the rest of my codebase. In fact it may help start unit testing a bigger project I have at work where we've been neglecting automated tests for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is already an accepted answer for this issue, but I will try to supplement with info from a related topic.

You can mock everything from external modules, but the imported component's selectors. There is an easy way which is to disable this kind of errors as you mentioned.

[Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268906/unit-testing-angular2-component-with-imported-module)

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

...

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  ...
```

The NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA tells the Angular compiler to ignore unrecognized elements and attributes.

Otherwise I would suggest to add FontAwesome directly into the testbed despite it being a tedious task. It improves readability and avoids importing redundant components in the test module. This mainly becomes a problem when you have more than one component.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I also thought about this, but I believe it will have the same problem as with CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA which is that you override another components you don't want to but you forgot to import.