# Karma Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout Nightmare

Tags: angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have my angular application with more than 5000 test cases.

It has been running ok before I upgraded to Angular 13 and Karma 6.3, Jasmin 3.6

After upgrade, I am getting this error while running "ng test".

> Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 960000ms (transport close)

This is how my karma config looks like after

```js
const process = require("process");
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require("puppeteer").executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly','text-summary', 'cobertura'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml','coverage-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // autoWatch: true,
    // browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    singleRun: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--js-flags=--max-old-space-size=80196',
          '--disable-web-security'
        ],
      },
    },
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 960000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 960000,
    proxies: {
      '/assets/': '/base/src/assets/',
    },
  });

};
```

And part of package.json

```json
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "^6.3.13",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
```

I have tried almost every github and stackoverflow, and other suggestions, spoken to many experts, but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more readings this is how I solved the problem.

I made sure all all the test package's versions are correctly updated and compaitable with each other.

This is how it looks now,

```
"jasmine-core": "4.0.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
"karma": "6.3.17",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "4.0.2"
```

After this, I was able to run all the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter concurrency: 5 inside karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // other settings...

    concurrency: 5, // allow up to 5 browser instances in parallel

    // other settings...
  });
};
```

the concurrency value can be changed to control the number of browser instances that can run in parallel during testing

Comment: After I tried many other things, this finally helped in my case (running build in OpenShift container). But I can really not explain why the connection works now. It even fails wehn I set it to 1...

Comment: No... It was coincident. After 7 successful builds it started failing again. But adding     browserDisconnectTimeout and pingTimeout seemed to help after all. We have 2000+ tests.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119506/karma-jasmine-times-out-without-running-tests