# Slow Karma tests on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, google-chrome, karma-runner

We are unit-testing an Angular app using Karma and Jasmine.

Angular - v1.3.8
Karma - v0.13.7
Jasmine - v2.3.2
Node - v0.12.7

Our battery of over 1000 tests runs very quickly on an older version of Chromium:

```
Chromium 43.0.2357 (Ubuntu): Executed 1050 of 1051 (skipped 1) SUCCESS (32.666 secs / 31.957 secs)
```

But on a newer version of Chrome, the tests run much more slowly and usually do not finish because the browser is disconnected due to timeouts:

```
WARN [Chrome 44.0.2403 (Linux)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Linux): Executed 602 of 1051 DISCONNECTED (2 mins 16.63 secs / 2 mins 5.377 secs)
```

We find that this problem appears under Windows, Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac with Chrome 44.

```
WARN [Chrome 44.0.2403 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 281 of 1051 DISCONNECTED (1 min 2.837 secs / 50.415 secs)
```

The problem seems to be with newer versions of Chrome. Is there a power-saving feature enabled by default, which can reduce performance? Can Chrome be started in a different mode?

Under Firefox tests are still running quickly.

Comment: this might expain what your seeing https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/44

Comment: @atmd Even keeping the window visible and in focus does not speed things up.

Comment: Why switch from Chrominium to Chrome? Try running them on the latest version of Chrominium (i think 46) and i will be believe it will be just as swift. Chrome 44 brought "Lots of under the hood changes for stability and performance" , however some people feel they broke it :) Do more tests on vairous browsers and then submit a bug. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667102/disconnected-1-times-because-no-message-in-10000-ms-using-karma-jasmine

Comment: I've tested many browsers in many versions and there was definitely problem with Chrome 44. But after upgrade Chrome to version 45 (Beta) everything looks good and tests are running smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: @JakubPowierza, you could maybe answer your own question and explain what were your conclusions...

Comment: Sad to say, I'm on Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) and I'm still seeing this issue. I was really hoping that moving from 44 to 45 would fix it.